# Is testing everything a good approach?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have class `Generator` with a method `buildDocument` and inside this method there is:
`service.getDocument() + EXTENSION;` where `private final static String EXTENSION = ".txt";`

method `getDocument()` is already tested in `ServiceTest` class. Should I add test for `buildDocument` method to test this file extension adding? It seems a bit like testing:

```
private boolean method(){
   return true;
}
```

should such methods be tested?

Comment: private boolean method() { return true; } -> such methods should not exist. if they do, test them. Otherwise you'll be in for a surprise if somebody changes the implementation later on

Comment: "method getDocument() is already tested in ServiceTest class" - if getDocument() fails only the bigger test would fail, so you have no clue if the problem lies in buildDocument() or getDocument(), that is why getDocument() has to be tested as well.

Comment: @Stultuske so in your opinion this String concatenation should be tested? This method which `return true` was an example to clarify question.

Comment: @Michu93 it changes a value, and most likely, it is used somewhere. First thing to do is: figure out whether you really need that method. If so, yes, test it.

Comment: @Stultuske so in your opinion it's also worth to change private method to default or protected just to add test for String concatenation?

Comment: @Michu93 I never said that. private methods are supposed to be tested by testing the methods that call them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your method is **private**. Anything that is private should be considered an implementation detail. Thus you rather avoid writing a unit test for *just* that part.

Meaning: if you have test method somewhere already that your document sits in the right place, with the *expected* name (which would include the extension), then you are "good enough".

But note this also a bit of "personal style".

Comment: I have test for expectedName but without extension, just a document name without `.txt`, that's why I'm asking if just `+ EXTENSION` should be tested

Comment: Worth noting that this shows the distinction between _test coverage_ and the _test subject_.

Comment: @Michu93 The question is: that existing test, why does it *not* take the extension into consideration? You see: if the extension doesnt matter, then you dont need to test for it. If the extension is important, then why is that test ignoring that relevant aspect?

Comment: @GhostCat `getDocument()` just gets name of document because then you can add extension which you need. So in `ServiceTest` there is test just for document name because in other classes I can use this `getDocument` and then add any extension. I am not sure if it's necessary to add test just for `+ `.txt`` in private method

Comment: @Michu93 As said: the question is ... will there be a problem at runtime, with your users, if the file has a different extension?! If so: ensure the extension is correct.